# Nodejs - Why my variable in class is undefined?

Tags: node.js

In `crawler.js` :

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var Helper = require('./helper.js');
var helper = new Helper();

var Crawler = function(){   

    var me = this;

    this.listCategory;

    this.getCategory = function(){

        //1. not use async : test key input is idMenu
        helper.categoryInMenu(1, function(err, result){
            me.listCategory = result;
        });

       //2. use async : test key input is idMenu
       async.map([1], helper.categoryInMenu, function(err, result){
          me.listCategory = result;
          //console.log(result);
       });

       console.log(me.listCategory); // return undefined

    }
}

module.exports = Crawler;
```

When i set `me.listCategory = result;` (with `result != null`) then call `listCategory` in file `main.js` or `console.log` it in file `crawler.js`.

Display in command is `undefined`.

File `main.js`

```
var Crawler = require('./crawler.js');
var snipper = new Crawler();

snipper.getCategory();
console.log(snipper.listCategory);
```

I try use `async` module with function `map`, it not work.

Maybe, i not set `me.listCategory = return of function helper.categoryInMenu`.

File `helper.js`

```
var db = require('mysql');
var config = require('./configLoader.js');
config.load(__dirname+'/config.json');

var Helper = function(){

    var me = this;
    this.conn = db.createConnection(config.get('db'));

    this.menu = function(callback){
        me.conn.query("SELECT * FROM `menu`", function(err, rows){
            callback(err, rows);
        });
    }

    // return list category with "input" is a idMenu
    this.categoryInMenu = function(idMenu, callback){
        me.conn.query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE idMenu = ?", idMenu, function(err, rows){
            callback(err, rows);
        });
    }

    // return config of Category with "input" is a idCategory (Category)
    this.dom = function(idCategory, callback){
        me.conn.query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE id = ?", idCategory, function(err, rows){
            callback(err, JSON.parse(rows[0].dom));
        });
    }

}

module.exports = Helper;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about async but the map() method creates a new array which you should return.

```me.listCategory = async.map([1], helper.categoryInMenu, function(err, result){
      return me.listCategory = result;
      //console.log(result);
});```

Comment: I removed my answer as i'm not able to test this. Also your ```this.getCategory```Method should return something.

Comment: Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/gearsdigital/0df212c86cf1a2c1f127

Comment: yes, me too test. but not work.

Comment: i want learn tut about `asyns`.. You have some link tut for me ? thanks.

Comment: i want `this.getCategory` is void Method, because i want `this.listCategory` use in some Method such as `getArticle` `postArticle` ..v.. ..v..

Maybe, i use this  `gist.github.com/gearsdigital/0df212c86cf1a2c1f127`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map in all languages is used to transform the values of iterable into something else, that is why you should return in the callback function and the result will be new array containing only the returned values. If you need to iterate only, you should use `arr.forEach` (>ES5) or simple `for` loop.

Your problem is that `async.map` is asynchronous which means `console.log(me.listCategory);` is executed before the actual map.

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is actually ES5 standard so you don't need `async` module to map arrays, also the native `map` is synchronous.

Comment: thanks :) i view some example [http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html).

Maybe, i will use callback (call other method it in it  )